# SSRS: GetReportParameters and date values

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dependencies, ssrs-2008

I have an RDL file where I enter two dates, run a query based on that date range to populate a drop-down list and then populate another text field with a default value that is based on the Label of the drop-down list's selected item.

The Data Types are Date/Time for the first two dates, Text for the drop-down list and Text for the last text field.  The drop-down list's Value as returned by the query is actually a Date/Time but if I set the Data Type to Date/Time then it does not work as expected when I Preview the report (when I select a value in the list the current selection just reverts back to "<Select a Value>" and nothing is put into the last Text field, regardless of its Data Type).

Anyway, with the drop-down list having a Data Type of Text, all works OK in the Preview.

The problem is that I have custom interface for the reports, and try as I might, I cannot get my own implementation to correctly get the default value for my last Text field.

I noticed that SSRS only wants dates in a certain format and so with some manipulation of the dates I can get the ValidValues for the drop-down list parameter by calling GetReportParameters() with the Values parameter set as follows:

```
values[0].Name = "fromdate";
values[0].Value = "2011-11-01 00:00:00";
values[0].Label = "";
values[1].Name = "todate";
values[1].Value = "2011-11-30 00:00:00";
values[1].Label = "";

parameters = GetReportParameters("myreport", null, true, values, null);
```

Following this call, parameters[2] now contains ValidValues and I can populate my own drop-down list in the custom UI.

However, when I need to get the default value for the text field, I cannot seem to get the input values in a format that GetReportParameters() will accept:

```
values[0].Name = "fromdate";
values[0].Value = "2011-11-01 00:00:00";
values[0].Label = "";
values[1].Name = "todate";
values[1].Value = "2011-11-30 00:00:00";
values[1].Label = "";
values[2].Name = "datelist";
values[2].Label = "The date is 22nd Nov 2011";
values[2].Value = "2011-11-22 00:00:00";

parameters = GetReportParameters("myreport", null, true, values, null);
```

After this call I expect the parameter for my text field to have a DefaultValues value that I can access but it is 'null' the State is set to HasOutstandingDependencies.  Why is this?  All of the dependencies have been set - correctly as far as I can see, so what might be the issue?

I realise that I may be getting into difficulties with the conversion of Data Type between Date/Time and Text, but if I try to keep it consistent and use Date/Time throughout then I cannot get it to work even in the RDL's Preview, so I'm not sure that's the way to go either!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Additional info: if I change the DataSet that I use to populate the drop-down list such that the Value is then a Text field rather than a Date/Time then I still have the same problem.  However, if I change the drop-down list parameter itself such that the Available Values are specified rather than use a DataSet then everything seems to work as expected.

Comment: Further to the first comment, I have done some more testing today and I was definitely mistaken in thinking that was Date/Time related.  It is certainly related to whether the Available Values for the drop-down list is populated either by specifying values or using a query.  This is regardless of Data Type.  

I am going to ask again in a new post since I think that this one no longer describes the issue accurately enough and is a bit confusing!